# A javascript code that will check the valid values entered in textbox for days and months

Tags: javascript, html

Basically i want the user to enter date in a textbox not of input type = "Date" which will check that if the date entered is 12/14/2016.It'll show an alert as 12 is maximum for the months and similarly for checking days it compares with 30 and 31 depending on the month of the year.But when i enter 31/9/2016 it doesn't shows an alert!!

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Date format Checking
    </title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Enter Date in Valid Formats:</h1>
    <input type="text" id="dat" name="date" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" onclick="datecheck();" />
    <script>
        var dats;
        function datecheck() {
            debugger;
            dats = document.getElementById("dat").value.split("/");
            if (dats[1] > 12) {
                alert("Invalid Date Format");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if (dats[1] == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12) {
                    if (dats[0] > 31) {
                        alert("Invalid Date Format");
                    }

                } else if (dats[0] > 30) {
                    alert("Invalid Date Format");


                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: month may contain 31 days, so use  if(dats[0] >= 31)

Answer (score 0):

Juhana is correct. Following code works.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Date format Checking
    </title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Enter Date in Valid Formats:</h1>
    <input type="text" id="dat" name="date" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" onclick="datecheck();" />
    <script>
        var dats;
        function datecheck() {
            debugger;
            dats = document.getElementById("dat").value.split("/");
            if (dats[1] > 12) {
                alert("Invalid Date Format");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if (dats[1] == 1 || dats[1] == 3 || dats[1] == 5 || dats[1] == 7 || dats[1] == 8 || dats[1] == 10 || dats[1] == 12) {
                    if (dats[0] > 31) {
                        alert("Invalid Date Format");
                    }

                } else if (dats[0] > 30) {
                    alert("Invalid Date Format");


                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```